# How to make struct survive outside its Go routine when using pointers to external struct

Tags: pointers, go, struct, goroutine

When I run this code with `go run main.go`, then I see this output:

```sh
inner: {Bar:{Baz:xyz} BarPtr:0xc0000101e0}
outer: {Bar:{Baz:} BarPtr:<nil>}
```

I can not understand why when passing a pointer to a routine, then the struct **created** inside that routine can not be exposed outside via pointers.

I know I could use a channel to publish the structs created inside the Go routine, but the piece of code I am working on would require too much additional boilerplate code. I would like to use a Wait Group with pointers if possible, but I can not find a way so I am wondering if this is possible at all?

To me I should be able to expose an internal struct via a pointer, but I am not sure maybe the compiler silently ignores this, or am I failing to understand some fundamental features of Go?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Foo struct {
    Bar    Bar
    BarPtr *Bar
}

type Bar struct {
    Baz string
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // the real example has more routines, so I need a wait group
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(strct *Foo) {
        defer wg.Done()
        bar1 := Bar{
            Baz: "xyz",
        }
        bar2 := Bar{
            Baz: "abc",
        }
        ownFoo := Foo{
            Bar:    bar1,
            BarPtr: &bar2,
        }
        fmt.Printf("inner: %+v\n", ownFoo)
        strct = &ownFoo
    }(&foo)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("outer: %+v\n", foo)
}
```

Comment: struct is a pointer that intially points to foo. Making this pointer point somewhere else (here to ownFoo) doesn't affect foo in the slightest, and it's unclear to me why would expect that it does.

Comment: It seems I could use either a global variable with a Wait group so I know that the Go routine is done with that global variable and I can safely access its value, or I could use a channel. I wanted to use a pointer to avoid using global variables referenced from the inside of the Go routine.

Comment: Even if the pointer thing you're trying to do would work, you'd *still* need synchronization around the pointer assignment. The comment in the code indicates that you need a WaitGroup anyway, so why not modify foo directly?

Comment: `foo` could be created and injected from a different package. I am trying to minimise the amount of boilerplate code (e.g. no need for extra "wrapper" structs and channels), but maintaining some sort of safety/synchronisation by using wait groups and avoiding global variables.

Comment: @TPPZ goroutine or not, to *change* the value pointed-to by a pointer you use `*strct = ownFoo` instead of `strct = &ownFoo`. The `strct = &ownFoo` changes the pointer, not the pointed-to value.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks that fixed my code. It was a bug in the way I was treating pointers, I found out some evidence in the docs as well, see here where they talk about "`// set i through the pointer p`": https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1 if you write the answer I'll accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression to set the `foo` value through the pointer `strct` is:

```
*strct = ownFoo
```

On the other hand, the expression

```
strct = &ownFoo
```

sets the `strct` pointer to the address of `ownFoo` and leaves the `foo` value untouched.

---

Keep in mind that if you have a variable that is being accessed from multiple goroutines, and at least one of them is writing/modifying the variable, without proper synchronization your code is bound to hit a data race, regardless of whether the variable is accessed directly or through a local pointer or what have you.